# Use Grunt newer with custom task

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm trying to use grunt-newer to watch files from a folder and if any is changed, trigger a custom task.

I have something like this in my Gruntfile.js:

```
grunt.initConfig({
   watch: {
      widgets: {
         files: "/somepath/*.js",
         tasks: ['newer:mycustomtask']
      }
   }
});

grunt.registerTask("mycustomtask", ["description of my task"], function() {
  console.log("me has been triggered");
});
```

Whenever I run "grunt watch", I have this output:

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
File "/somepath/WidgetA.js" changed.
Running "newer:mycustomtask" (newer) task
Fatal error: The "newer" prefix is not supported for aliases
```

I googled but didn't found anything about this. Anyone knows how could I implement this? I need to now in my "customtask" which files have been changed

Answer (score 1):

If you reference a task (inside watch or concurrent e.g.) which is either **not installed** or **not configured** you get this error output.

This happens often when you copy-paste a watch config from a different project.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar requirement and the solution I ended up with is roughly as follows. Let's assume that the project structure is:

```
Gruntfile.js
package.json
src/
    config.js
    data.js
tasks/
    customtask.js
```

Here, the `src` directory contains data which will be monitored by `watch`, while the definition of the custom task is stored in `tasks/customtask.js`. For the purpose of this example, this task will only print the file names of the changed files:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerMultiTask('customtask', function() {
        var done = this.async();

        if(!this.files){ done(); return; }

        this.files[0].src.forEach(file_name => {
            console.log(file_name);
        });

        done();
    });
};
```

Now, `Gruntfile.js` looks like:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    const files = ['src/config.js', 'src/data.js'];

    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        customtask: {
            release: {
                src: files
            }
        },

        watch: {
            data: {
                files: files,
                tasks: ['customtask:release']
            },
            options: {
                spawn: false
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadTasks('tasks');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    var changedFiles = Object.create(null);
    var onChange = grunt.util._.debounce(function() {
        grunt.config('customtask.release.src', Object.keys(changedFiles));
        changedFiles = Object.create(null);
    }, 200);
    grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath) {
        changedFiles[filepath] = action;
        onChange();
    });

    grunt.registerTask('build', ['watch:data']);
};
```

here, it specifies that:

1. the files of interest are `['src/config.js', 'src/data.js']`
2. that our `customtask` operates in principle on these files (in case it would be invoked directly)
3. that `watch` is supposed to observe these files and launch `customtask:release` whenever something changes
4. `grunt.loadTasks('tasks')` loads all "tasks definitions" from the directory `tasks`, i.e., here only the `customtask`
5. `grunt.registerTask('build', ['watch:data'])` defines a "shortcut" for `watch:data`

Finally, in order to invoke `customtask` only for the changed files, this example uses the strategy employed in the [documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/blob/master/docs/watch-examples.md) in the section "Compiling files as needed". In loose terms, it assembles all changed files in an object the keys of which are then used to modify the `src` property of the `customtask` on-the-fly.

Running `grunt build` then initiates the "watch". If one runs in another terminal window for example `touch src/*.js`, the output is:

```
Running "watch:data" (watch) task
Waiting...
>> File "src/config.js" changed.
>> File "src/data.js" changed.

Running "customtask:release" (customtask) task
src/config.js
src/data.js
```

where the last two lines come from `customtask`...

Answer (score -1):

You just need to have a config entry (even an empty one) for your task:

```
grunt.initConfig({

  mycustomtask: {
  },

  watch: {
    widgets: {
      files: "/somepath/*.js",
      tasks: ['newer:mycustomtask']
    }
  }
});
```